# ko.toJS converting Array to Object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

We're using knockout.js heavily in our app, but have run into a new scenario.  It revolves around [`ko.toJSON`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), but it appears to be the underyling `ko.toJS` that's causing the problem.

We have an object with a number of properties, one of which is an array of other objects.  After running it through `ko.toJS`, it becomes an object with each property given the name of the original index.  I've not been able to replicate this in test code - indeed `ko.toJS` properly keeps an array as an array in my other tests.

Example of `ko.toJS` getting it wrong and converting it to an object:

[image]

Example of `ko.toJS` getting it right, and leaving it as an array:

[image]

Any thoughts on why `ko.toJS` may be causing this or what to look at next appreciated...!

**Update**

When using the debugger version of knockout, this is how it's reporting the Array being passed in to mapJsObjectGraph:

[image]

Comment: You could download the knockout debug build and look for the function mapJsObjectGraph (line 1619 in my knockout-3.0.0-debug). Then add a console.log(outputProperties) above the line (1650 for me) return outputProperties; and just see what KO is generating as it goes along.

Comment: Thanks @sifriday - updated info added.  We've just found something ourselves also - the object is originating outside of our iframe, it seems instanceof doesn't work across frame boundaries.  Will post an answer if this is the case.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It's certainly the issue. `instanceof` compares references of prototypes and the `Array` prototype (as with all other objects) is unique for each host environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in knockout.  An [issue has already been opened](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1307).

The workaround is to change the line in the function mentioned above, mapJsObjectGraph:

```
var outputProperties = rootObject instanceof Array ? [] : {};
```

to this:

```
var outputProperties = toString.call(rootObject) === "[object Array]" ? [] : {};
```

Seems that this isn't the only place `instanceof` is used in knockout though, as per the bug report.

Comment: I will be, as soon as SO lets me :)